# How do I list blobs contained in a directory Azure

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, virtual-directory

So I am trying to list blobs contained in a virtual folder let's call it "VF"

I have tried many methods for example:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("...");

var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Container_Name");

List<IListBlobItem> blobslist = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("VF", true).ToList();
```

But I receive errors like:

```
Error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blobl.BlobContinuationToken"}
```

I am trying to return file contents using an API, is this why I am receiving trouble and am using the incorrect methods?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the usage of BlobContinuationToken correctly.

Try it like this

```
if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
{
    var context = new OperationContext();
    var options = new BlobRequestOptions();
    var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
    BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var results = await cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, true, BlobListingDetails.All,
            null, blobContinuationToken, options, context);
        blobContinuationToken = results.ContinuationToken;
        foreach (var item in results.Results)
        {
            //do what you want with each blob
        }
    } while (blobContinuationToken != null);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, I think I have the connectionString wrong as its returning false, silly question but what should my connectionString look like? I may be using the incorrect format

Comment: I am using "@DefaultEndpointsProtocol = https; AccountName ={azure email}; AccountKey ={Password...Not sure if password or generated key}; EndpointSuffix = core.windows.net"

Edited: Clarifying

Comment: @ReeceJeffrey remove the spaces in the string. Apart from that it looks correct

Comment: It seems It is still returning false

Comment: @ReeceJeffrey try to paste in the complete connection string found in under your "storage account--> access keys --> key1 --> connection string" in the portal. just verify that you are able to connect with that first, then break it to pieces

Comment: Here is how I am using it:

var/string connectionString = "@DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={AzureEmail};AccountKey={AzurePassword};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
  

   if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
   {

Comment: Here is how I am using it:

var/string connectionString = "@DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={AzureEmail};AccountKey={AzurePassword};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
  

   if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
   {

Comment: @ReeceJeffrey what is AzurePassword? you should use the generated key under "storage account--> access keys --> key1 --> key"

Comment: Yes haha Im so sorryI am very new to this, I am busy trying the access keys

Comment: Okay its returned true!

Comment: It all seems to be working! Thanks very much for the assistance it was extremely helpful

Comment: @ReeceJeffrey Great! Np, happy to help! have a nice day:)